typeorm generated query does not return the same result as raw query does
From posgreSQL I ran a query:
select * from products where name LIKE 'test'; 

This returns 2 results. In my typeorm code, I have this:

{condition: {field: 'name', value: 'test'}}

const data = qbuilder.where(`${condition.field} LIKE :${condition.field}`, {
                    [condition.field]: `%${condition.value}%`,
                }) as SelectQueryBuilder<EntityType>;
                console.log(data.getSql());
                return data;

And this prints out
select * from products where name LIKE $1; 

which seems correct but the data only returns empty array.
I tried with and without the % but it doesn't change anything.
Any suggestions on what went wrong?

You can temporarily change logging settings or observe pg_stat_activity to see from the db's perspective what it really sees after $1 gets substituted. If it shows you're really just passing 'test', make sure you did commit the rows you're expecting in the table when you check with the other client you're comparing this to. And that you're not accidentally comparing to a different db entirely
